# how to put long paragraphs in a column in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have to make a song lyric database and one of my columns are lyrics to the song. i just copied and paste the lyrics in the column when inserting but keep getting "incorrect string value" error. i already put escape single quotes for lyrics with apostrophes in them.

below is the code statement i used for inserting the data.

```
insert into MySongs (title, artist, genre, lyrics, length, release_date) VALUE ('Shake the room', 'Pop smoke', 'Rap', '[Intro: Pop Smoke]
Traphouse Mob
Woo
Woo, woo
It''s Big 092MLBOA (This is a Melo beat)

[Chorus: Pop Smoke & Quavo]
Uh, I bet I shake the room (Ayy, woo, woo, woo)
Swerve (Skrrt, skrrt, skrrt)
Go ''head and shake the room, yeah, go ''head and shake the room (Shake it)
I bet I shake the room (Grraow)
Wait (Woo, woo, woo, go)
Swerve (Skrrt, skrrt)
Go ''head and shake the room, huh, go ''head and shake the room (Shake it)
I bet I shake the room

[Verse 1: Quavo]
Uh, Quavo
How ''bout I shake the room? (Shake it)
Chop gon'' sweep the broom (Grraow)
Everybody runnin'' and duckin'', I''m clearin'' the room (Woo)
Shoot one time, seein'' double time like you on shrooms (Shoot, shoot)
On the other line, it''s a FaceTime, say a nigga on the news (Brrt)
We ''bout to shake in this bitch (Shake)
Frosted Flake on the wrist (Ice)
The gang ain\'t playin\' and shit (Woo, woo)
In New York, I gotta shake in this bitch
Shake, shake, shake, shake (Shake it up)
Peel back ya toupee (Peel it back)
Money move the conversate (Money)
Put ''em up on the plate (Put ''em up)
Baby shakin'' in the waist (She shakin'')
Hit the flashlight to see her face (Flash)
And she lookin'' like a snack (Cute)
Birkin bag on the way (Woo) 
[Chorus: Pop Smoke & Quavo]
I bet I shake the room (Ayy, woo, woo, woo)
Swerve (Skrrt, skrrt, skrrt)
Go ''head and shake the room, yeah, go ''head and shake the room (Shake it)
I bet I shake the room (Grraow)
Wait (Woo, woo, woo, go)
Swerve (Skrrt, skrrt)
Go ''head and shake the room, huh, go ''head and shake the room (Shake it)
I bet I shake the room

[Verse 2: Pop Smoke]
Baby (Baby), shake it (Shake it)
I pop a Perc'', feel amazing (Bah)
Straight Henny, no chaser (Uh-huh)
Niggas be talkin'' hot ''til they get burned (Woo)
I don''t fuck with niggas ''cause these niggas be sherm
Lil'' nigga, stay in your place, wait for your turn
Respect ain''t given, nigga, it''s earned (Grrt, baow)
In the Bugatti (Woo), 5719 with baguettes (Skrrt)
Flag in the air, hold on (Hold on), ref (Ref), ref (Ref)
In the LaFerrari, can''t rent this (Nah)
With a brown lil'' thing, Reeses (Reeses)
Steven Victor in a Pista (Pista)
Dior got no creases (Creases)
Art gallery (Art gallery, woo)
Six-point-one for the painting (Painting)
George Condos (George Condos)
Cost more than your condo (Uh), wait
 [Chorus: Pop Smoke & Quavo]
I bet I shake the room (Ayy, woo, woo, woo)
Swerve (Skrrt, skrrt, skrrt)
Go ''head and shake the room, yeah, go ''head and shake the room (Shake it)
I bet I shake the room (Grraow)
Wait (Woo, woo, woo, go)
Swerve (Skrrt, skrrt)
Go ''head and shake the room, huh, go ''head and shake the room (Shake it)
I bet I shake the room.', '02:45', '02/07/2020');
```

Comment: Escape with \' instead of ''. Your style is for mssql.

Comment: `ain\'t playin\'` should be `ain''t playin''` ?